# iPad simulator for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ipad, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, simulator

I used a Cross-Platform Xamarin.Forms Master-Detail .NET Standard project template in VS 2017.
In the Info.plist it shows it is a Universal app.
In the solution platforms, I can only select iPhone or iPhoneSimulator for iOS apps
[Solution Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVOdB.png)
Is there a way to run this app in an iPad simulator?

Answer (score 0):

The iPad simulator is in the simulator list:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I had to add Debug Target to the menu.  I upvoted your answer.  It didn't reflect on my side.

Comment: @VincentvanRooijen Does you see ☑️ under the vote down? You can click it to accept this answer which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: No, I don't see this.  I think because I don't have enough reputations for that.

Comment: I'm sure there is a ☑️ under the vote down, please check again.

Comment: There really isn't.  And when I upvote you, I get
'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

Comment: OK, that's fine. Generally, there is a white checkmark under the vote down and when you click it, it will change to green and it means you accept the answer. Just like [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) described.